# Angularjs orderBy with integer Strings

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I have a dataset for Ex:

```
$scope.friends =
      [{name:'John',  score:'10'},
       {name:'Mary',  score:'19'},
       {name:'Mike',  score:'-21'},
       {name:'Adam',  score:'-35'},
       {name:'Julie', score:'29'}];
}]);
```

i use this data as a source of `ng-repeat`,

```
<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:'-score' ">
  <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
  <td>{{friend.score}}</td>
</tr>
```

I want to sort the `friends` according to `score` in `descending` order. like below,

```
Name    Score
-------------
Julie   29
Mary    19
John    10    
Mike    -21
Adam    -35
```

but i get the output as,

```
Name    Score
-------------
Julie   29
Mary    19
John    10  
Adam    -35  
Mike    -21
```

here is a [Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vFj3m7BnlG8Z94gLZ9ap?p=preview)

**note that** -21 and -35 are not in correct order in the output, and this is because the `score` property is a `String` value. If i change it to `int` value then all are working as expected. how to overcome this, and please consider that i'am not able to change the type of the `score` property.

Comment: This seems to be a valid [open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11435) in Angular. Some suggestions mentioned to get around it.

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:'+-score' ">
  <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
  <td>{{friend.score}}</td>
</tr>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iixbiXjTWd5tHQcTXBA0?p=preview)